# Android Physical Keyboard Feedback (Keyclicks)

Tags: android

The soft pop up keyboard makes a sound when a key is pressed.
I would play a sound when a key is pressed on the physical keyboard that we have built into our android hardware. Any advice of how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [View.OnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener). It will be invoked only for the Hardware keyboard.
Just set it up like this:

```
    editText.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
        editText.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK); // Or play sound in any other way
        return false;
    });
```

Pay attention to return `false`. Otherwise your input won't be passed to the view because by returning `true` you are saying to the framework that your listener handled input already.

Comment: This can't be good since it's handled on the view's side.. I believe the question is how to do it so the sound is played in any application so needs to be handled on the keyboard

Comment: Agree, would be great to have more details. Next ideas may depend from how they use Android (and how is it possible to use): is it a plain Android, customized firmware, do they have launcher and so on. One of the ways is to use Accessibility service (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html#FLAG_REQUEST_FILTER_KEY_EVENTS)

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply.  The hardware is designed by us and is running plain Android (Marshmallow).  The keyboard chip that I am using is MAX7360 and so I have based my driver on this; https://dev.seemoo.tu-darmstadt.de/bcm/bcm-public/blob/451cdc143a786a5394f40a29b010dee87625d7ef/kernel/drivers/input/keyboard/max7359_keypad.c  If you need any further info please let me know.